# keycloak 8 login update password ftl file not loading

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak 8 and for a user I am setting an update password credential reset from keycloak admin console-
[image]

Then I successfully get an email with a link to reset the password which looks like-
http://host.corp/auth/realms/realm-dummy-name/login-actions/action-token?key=verylongtoken

When I click on the link I would expected that login-update-password.ftl file from keycloak themes will be loaded on the browser. But I see info.ftl file is getting loaded first. Any idea why is it happening?

(I see no error in the logs, even debug logs are not helping much. It just shows that info.ftl file is being fetched. and also after lot of googling no luck. Any help would be really appriciated.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like loading info.ftl is in default flow of keycloak